# PHP use $_SESSION variable as default in class function

Tags: php, class, default

I have a class that interfaces a lot with the `$_SESSION` variables. Some functions should default to the current user if none is specified. I have the user id in `$_SESSION['userid']` and use it in some places fine. However, when I try to use the `$_SESSION` variable as a default for function parameters I get an error. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Here's the error I get:

`Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in main.php on line whatever`

```
<?php
class User {

    public function log_out() {
        unset($_SESSION['userid']);
    }

    public function get_data($uid = $_SESSION['userid']) {

    }

    public function logged_in() {
        return isset($_SESSION['userid']);
    }

    public function enabled($uid = $_SESSION['userid']) {

    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a variable in the method signature. You can default $uid param to null. Then in the function body use the value from the session if $uid is null.

### Example

You're not able to do this:

```
public function get_data($uid = $_SESSION['userid']) {

}
```

But, this is fine:

```
public function get_data($uid = null) {
    $uid = $uid ?? $_SESSION['userid'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Constant expression / Calling function as a default value of a parameter is not allowed in PHP.

You may try `$uid = null;`

Inside the function,

`$uid = $uid ?: $_SESSION['user_id'];`

(?: is Elvis operator, it checks for empty value and replace with assigned value, PHP5.3+)

However, since you may do it multiple times, you can consider create a class variable and initialize the value in the constructor.

`private $uid;`

`public __constructor($uid = null) {
     $this->uid = uid ?: $_SESSION['user_id'];
 }`

Comment: Since you're explicitly giving the `$uid` parameter the default value of `null`, I'd argue that using the null coalescing operator would be a better fit.

Comment: Yes, but what about if someone passing in false or an empty string? uid will be some unexpected value

Comment: In that case, I'd argue that using the following would be a better fit. `$this->uid = !empty($uid) ? $uid : $_SESSION['user_id']`. However, if you need to be this explicit with your checks then I'd say that you're doing something wrong with your class layout and naming conventions. As it stands; anyone that looks at the above class and methods will understand that passing an empty string or false would not be what the original programmer intended.

Comment: `$this->uid = uid ?: $_SESSION['user_id'];` is actually not different with `$this->uid = !empty($uid) ? $uid : $_SESSION['user_id']` isn't it ? Anyone knows that they should not pass empty string or false for sure, but they might not checking that $var before passing in.

Comment: By the way, my post is out of the topic a bit, your answer best suite with this question.